# How to change date time language in android

Tags: java, android, date, time

How can we change date/time language in android without changing the device language.

Below is my current code.
below code changes according to the device language. but i want to change without changing the device language settings

public static String formatTime(Date time)
    {
        String timeFormat = UserSettingManager.getUserSetting(UserSettingManager.PREF_TIME_FORMAT);
        if(StringUtils.isEmptyOrWhitespace(timeFormat))
        {
            timeFormat = DEFAULT_TIME_FORMAT;
        }

SimpleDateFormat formatter;

    try
    {
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(timeFormat);            
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DEFAULT_TIME_FORMAT);
    }
    return formatter.format(time);
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

```
public static String formatTime(Date time, Locale locale){
    String timeFormat = UserSettingManager
                           .getUserSetting(UserSettingManager.PREF_TIME_FORMAT);

    if(StringUtils.isEmptyOrWhitespace(timeFormat)){
        timeFormat = DEFAULT_TIME_FORMAT;
    }

    SimpleDateFormat formatter;

    try {
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(timeFormat, locale);            
    } catch(Exception e) {
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DEFAULT_TIME_FORMAT, locale);
    }
    return formatter.format(time);
}
```

And then like

```
Log.e("CHINESE DATE", formatTime(new Date(), Locale.CHINESE));
```

### EDIT

If you don't find a locale in the default list you can instantiate one using its constructor
:

```
Locale spanish = new Locale("es", "ES");
```

So it becomes

```
Log.e("SPANISH DATE", formatTime(new Date(), new Locale("es", "ES"));
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. But am not finding all languages here, like Spanish. can you please suggest for Spanish language

Comment: edited my answer with fix, use new Locale("es", "ES")

Comment: Thanks now its working for Spanish language .I was wondering can we do it with out using SimpleDateFormat ? as older java version (1.6) does not support SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 0):

```html
 java.text.DateFormat shortDateFormat = DateFormat.getDateFormat(context)
  final Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance()
   mDummyDate.setTimeZone(now.getTimeZone())
  // We use December 31st because it's unambiguous when demonstrating the date format
 // We use 13:00 so we can demonstrate the 12/24 hour options
 mDummyDate.set(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), 11, 31, 13, 0, 0);
 Date dummyDate = mDummyDate.getTime();
 mTimePref.setSummary(DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getActivity()).format(now.getTime()));
mTimeZone.setSummary(getTimeZoneText(now.getTimeZone()));
mDatePref.setSummary(shortDateFormat.format(now.getTime()));
mDateFormat.setSummary(shortDateFormat.format(dummyDate));
mTime24Pref.setSummary(DateFormat.getTimeFormat(gtActivity()).format(dummyDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 java.text.DateFormat shortDateFormat = DateFormat.getDateFormat(context)
  final Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance()
   mDummyDate.setTimeZone(now.getTimeZone())
  // We use December 31st because it's unambiguous when demonstrating the date format
 // We use 13:00 so we can demonstrate the 12/24 hour options
 mDummyDate.set(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), 11, 31, 13, 0, 0);
 Date dummyDate = mDummyDate.getTime();
 mTimePref.setSummary(DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getActivity()).format(now.getTime()));
mTimeZone.setSummary(getTimeZoneText(now.getTimeZone()));
mDatePref.setSummary(shortDateFormat.format(now.getTime()));
mDateFormat.setSummary(shortDateFormat.format(dummyDate));
mTime24Pref.setSummary(DateFormat.getTimeFormat(gtActivity()).format(dummyDate));
```