# converting Date Time to a specific locale

Tags: java, android, localization

I'm trying to convert a Date Time which is `Mon Apr 18 22:56:10 GMT+05:30 2016`.

I have to convert this to a locale `hi-IN (Hindi)`.

I'm performing the below steps:

```
Date time = "Mon Apr 18 22:56:10 GMT+05:30 2016";
String dateTimeFormat = "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm aa";
SimpleDateFormat sdfgmt = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimeFormat, new Locale("hi","IN"));
sdfgmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(sdfgmt.format(time));
```

The output i get is, that only the month is getting translated. the other numbers, the AM/PM field still stand un-translated.

Can Any one provide a solution for the same. I have gone through many similar posts and have followed steps in the below link:
[How to change date time language in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31135692/how-to-change-date-time-language-in-android)

Note: I'm using the above code snippet in Android app actually.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this probably isn;t going to help, but I'd avoid using the old `java.util.Date` classes if at all possible and use the new `java.time.*` classes. It's a better API and less buggy... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

Comment: @BretC: Thank you. I'll do that change.

Comment: this `Date time = "Mon Apr 18 22:56:10 GMT+05:30 2016" ` doesn't even compile

Comment: I can't read Hindi but If I parse the original date properly, I get `१८ अप्रैल २०१६ ०५:२६ अपराह्न`, is it what you want?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto: yes ur right

Comment: How did u get it in dat format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I proceed

```
// Initial date time in String forma†
String timeOrg = "Mon Apr 18 22:56:10 GMT+05:30 2016";
// Corresponding date format
String dateTimeFormatOrg = "EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy";
// SimpleDateFormat using US locale to be able to parse "Mon Apr"
SimpleDateFormat sdfgmtOrg = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimeFormatOrg, Locale.US);
// Parse the date 
Date time = sdfgmtOrg.parse(timeOrg);

// Target date format
String dateTimeFormat = "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm aa";
// SimpleDateFormat using the target locale
SimpleDateFormat sdfgmt = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimeFormat, new Locale("hi","IN"));
// Set the Time Zone to UTC
sdfgmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
// Print the formatted date
System.out.println(sdfgmt.format(time))
```

**Output:**

```
१८ अप्रैल २०१६ ०५:२६ अपराह्न
```

Comment: Where are you setting the locale to Hindi?

Comment: And in my case the Locale i get is in the form of "hi-IN"

Comment: Output is still the same :(, Only month part of the date is getting translated....

Comment: what is your Time Zone ID and your default Locale? Which version of Java do you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112510/discussion-between-zax-and-nicolas-filotto).

Comment: All Time Zone IDs are here : https://gist.github.com/arpit/1035596   You can use them using TimeZone.getTimeZone("TimeZoneId"); method.